# location gradle dependencies / android studio plugin, Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Looking at my build.gradle file (module:app, modified from the FragmentBasics example code) 
- where is the android plugin ('com.android.application')? 
- Where are the dependencies (e.g. "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0")?
- are these in Maven Central Repository or local?
I'm asking because I've had to meddle with the file names to get this project to build (e.g. the first version of com.android.support:support-v4 I tried would not build with my target sdk) - so I'm guessing future changes may break my build (correct?) and would like to get in early here.  Also, are there different names for the android plugin (e.g. older names) in example code around the place? Has the name of the plugin changed over time (again, just wondering if future name changes here might break my build)?

Thanks

My build.gradle file for reference:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "website.[...].FragmentBasics"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android support library is not in maven center, it's in your android sdk.
Open `Android SDK Manager`, you can check it:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Desmond - how about the android plugin?

Comment: don't worry about this, it just to tell your gradle it's a android application. But if you really want to know, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342458/apply-plugin-android-or-apply-plugin-com-android-application) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using newer versions of Android Studio, Gradle will look for your dependencies in the **JCenter** repository rather than Maven Central. Basically JCenter is a superset of Maven Central, that encompasses many additional repositories and artifacts. Also, JCenter has a better performance than Maven Central.

If you don't update the versions of external dependencies, Gradle plugin and targetSdkVersion etc, your project will always be able to build.

Comment: Thanks rookiedev - marked this usefull this but I don't have enough points for that to show.